# Saving audio file to mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express

I want the audio files to be relatively short (no need for gridFs). I know how to use forms and get data from user but how do I construct my  schema where I save the audio file from the user? I also need to save the image that the user uploads for the recipe which I think is a similar problem.
Please help if you have any suggestions!

Comment: Hi Heba, audio & images files are assets, so in general you may not store them in a mongo database. You may use a asset management tool instead such as S3 for instance.

Comment: First you have to store you assets on server or services like s3 etc then their path store in you Database.

Comment: Hello Frédéric, thank you for answering, I am getting an audio from the user using forms, and every step of my recipes needs an audio from the user, and the idea is using the. Eustache template later to show each step with its corresponding audio on the recipe's page.

Comment: Hi Heba, according to your description, you should need two things :
* a tool to record and save the audio file from your users
* a tool to register the info that your user have complete your form with. This info may include the URL of the uploaded audio files. 
Depending on your objective, there is a variety of tools that can do that, so you have to decide between which one fit the better with your need.